# Print out certain rows from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

The names im using can be changed or removed in the database at times, as it is now i have to change every name in the script when that happends. Can i print it out w/o a IF for example?

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT detail, 
                SUM(IF(depot = 'Huvuddepån', quantity, 0)) AS Huvuddepån,
                SUM(IF(depot = 'Uddevalla', quantity, 0)) AS Uddevalla,
                SUM(IF(depot = 'Jönköping', quantity, 0)) AS Jönköping,
                SUM(IF(depot = 'Polyeten', quantity, 0)) AS Polyeten,
                SUM(IF(depot = 'Krackern', quantity, 0)) AS Krackern
            FROM quantities 
            GROUP BY detail";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='300'>"."<b>Detalj</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Huvuddepån</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Uddevalla</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Jönköping</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Polyeten</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Krackern</b>"."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row["detail"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Huvuddepån"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Uddevalla"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Jönköping"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Polyeten"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Krackern"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cce28/9/5)

```
SET @COLUMNS = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
                'SUM(CASE WHEN depot = "',
                depot,
                '" THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "',
                depot,
                '"'
        )
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM quantities;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'SELECT  
                detail,
                ',@COLUMNS,'
        FROM
                quantities
        GROUP BY
                detail'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It works with the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE quantities(
  detail INT,
  depot VARCHAR(20),
  quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (1,"Huvuddepån",10);
INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (2,'Uddevalla',15);
INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (2,'Jönköping',20);
INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (3,'Polyeten',10);
INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (1,'Krackern',10);
INSERT INTO quantities VALUES (4,"fo'o6",10);
```

NOTE : Nevertheless, it will most likely break if one of your `depot` contains quotes `"`. If your data might contain such quotes, you should consider using `REPLACE` to replace those by `\"` in order to escape them.

The php code you should be using is the following one, I escaped the `"` in the sql because they weren't and I believe the problem came from here :

```
 <?php

    $sql = "SET @COLUMNS = NULL;

            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                    DISTINCT CONCAT(
                            'SUM(CASE WHEN depot = \"',
                            depot,
                            '\" THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS \"',
                            depot,
                            '\"'
                    )
            ) INTO @COLUMNS
            FROM quantities;

            SET @SQL = CONCAT(
                    'SELECT  
                            detail,
                            ',@COLUMNS,'
                    FROM
                            quantities
                    GROUP BY
                            detail'
            );

            PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='300'>"."<b>Detalj</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Huvuddepån</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Uddevalla</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Jönköping</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Polyeten</b>"."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='100'>"."<b>Krackern</b>"."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row["detail"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Huvuddepån"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Uddevalla"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Jönköping"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Polyeten"]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$row["Krackern"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried it but get an error (site blank), is there something in your code that i should enter with my data? I put your code in my php-tags.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the "END" to the CASE WHEN, I also added \' so that if a depot has a space in it it will still work. If your depot can contain `'` then we will need to find a way to escape those.

Comment: I still get a blank page, im sure i missing something. Is this code within php tags enough? Im so grateful for all the helph!

Comment: In fact I added 2 END instead of one, so I removed it, also I forgot a parenthesis so I added it. Sorry.

Comment: Still blank, i dont have the error-messages on in my code so cant see the exact problem. You find anything more?

Comment: Could you run the query, instead of the PREPARE and all what follows (last 3 lines), you write `SELECT @SQL;` and then you echo the result, so that I can see what is the real string that is then executed.

Comment: When i run it, it says its something wrong with line 3 ->SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(

Comment: Well .. that seems to work (the query in itself), see the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cfce/1/5 . But as I said in my first comment, the query will likely break if your depot contains some `'`, are there any ? If yes we'll need to escape them.

Comment: I use no ' in depot names, but space might interupt something? I also have several other columns in the table, is that a problem? I have auto-increment ID to.

Comment: I changed the code to adapt to the `'`, it should work properly, if not the problem might come from your php.

Comment: I have auto-increment ID (primary) and timestamp aswell in the same table. I put exactly that code in php-tags and it says something wrong on line 3. Also a depot_detail_UQ between the 2 columns.

Comment: I edited with the php code you should be using. I hope it's good. I escaped the `"`in the sql.